Can a Full license user login to partner community with same credentials?
In my org we have received a ticket saying a full license user is able to login to partner community with partner url with same credentials. The user does not have any special permissions which can make this happen. Did anyone face any similar issue?

Yes, full license users can log in to Digital Experiences that are configured to allow this access. Most likely, this is caused by the in the Administration | Login & Registration page having the Allow employees to log in directly to an Experience Cloud site checked. If you don't want internal users to be able to log in, disable that option.
